# Unable to return from a function in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function

I am passing an object from one function to another. If I try to print the object values directly in the view, then it gets displayed at once. Instead if I loop through the object values and try to display each of them from the function return then it is not getting displayed. Can any one please help.

```
const [projects, setprojects] = useState([]);

function scanData() {   

      var params = {
        TableName: "Voicemail_Project_Configuration_Details",
    };

    docClient.scan(params, onScan);
    
    function onScan(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err", JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
          //document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Unable to update item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
      } else {
        //console.log(data.Items)
        return (
        data.Items.map((item, index) => {
          //console.log(item)         
          Object.entries(item).map((key,val) => {
           if(val == 0){
            Object.entries(key).map((k,v) => {
              if (v == 1)
              
              newArr.push(k[1]);
              setprojects(Object.values(newArr))
              projectList(newArr)
            })
           }
          })
          
        })
        )
      }
    }
  }

function projectList(projects) {
   console.log(projects)
   return(
    projects.map( (k,v) => {  
       return(<tr><td key={v}>{k}</td></tr>)    
    })
  )  
  }
```

`<tbody>{projectList}</tbody>` is not returning anything. But `<tbody>{projects}</tbody>` is displaying all the values as a string in a row.

This is console.log of data.items

[image]

Comment: where did you put <tbody>{projectList}</tbody>? Remember that normal function and component function is different.

Comment: tbody is in the components function

Comment: @MayWeatherVN tbody is in the components function

Comment: Can you try using `<tbody>{projectList(projects)}</tbody>` ?

Comment: @SureshKumar Your suggestion worked for me. Thanks a lot for the help!